# Stone–Weierstrass theorem exercise

Tags: real-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

$f$ is continuous and
$$ \int_{a}^{b} x^nf(x) dx=0 $$ for every $n\leqslant N$.

Prove that $f$ has at least $N+1$ zero points at $(a,b)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried, and where are you running into trouble?

Comment: Well, my first idea was to approximate f(x) with Stone-Weierstrass and try to do induction proof, but at the moment i have no idea what to do next

Comment: Like its pretty obvius for n=0 but i cant do the induction step for n+1

Comment: For this problem and for future reference, note that some context (such as what you've told me in those two comments) should be included with your question in order for it to be to the [standards of this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: sorry, its my second question on this site

Comment: Not a problem, just letting you know.  And welcome!

Comment: Another bit of context that could be helpful: how did you decide that the Stone-Weierstrass theorem would be relevant here?

Comment: Because its easy for us to multiply any polynoimal by $ x^n $, also the integral of that will be just another polynoimal, and ofc we can use Weierstrass here because its on (a,b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If $f$ has $N$ or fewer zero-points on $(a,b)$, then there exists a non-zero polynoimal $p(x)$ of degree $N$ such that $f(x)p(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: Sorry I don't see the way how could I prove that this p(x) doesnt exist.

Comment: @Vizik I don't understand your question.  My answer says that this polynomial **does** exist

Comment: So i want to prove that $ f $ has $ N+1 $ or more zero-points, so there is no polynoimal $ p(x) $ of degree $ N $ such that $ f(x)p(x)>0 $ for all x in (a,b), am I right?

Comment: @Vizik No, that is incorrect. I am suggesting a proof by contradiction.  Suppose that the equation holds, and assume for the purpose of contradiction that $f$ has $N$ or fewer zero-points. Then, use the hint to reach a contradication

Comment: @Vizik Actually, my comment is wrong: it seems (although it wasn't quite what I had in mind) that your approach does work and is logically equivalent. If you show that there is no such polynomial, then you can deduce that $f$ has at least $N+1$ non-zero points

Comment: @Vizik so to answer your first comment: if $p(x)$ is your polynomial of degree $N$, note that $f(x)p(x) \geq 0$ for all $n$, then $\int_a^b f(x) p(x)\,dx = 0$ implies that $f(x)p(x) = 0$ for all $a\leq x \leq b$

Comment: Ohhh i think i get it. $$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x)p(x) dx = a_n \int_{a}^{b} f(x)x^ndx+a_{n-1}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)x^{n-1}dx+... =0 $$ Needed that equation all time thanks :D